# Team Foundation Server questions

Tags: tfs, xna

Me and my friends are wanting to make a game and code on the same project at the same time.
I have a few questions about this and Team Foundation Server.
If you know any of the answer to these questions I would greatly appreciate it if you could answer them below! :D

1. Can I run Team Foundation Server on Linux or does it have to be Windows Server?
2. Can we create a project and simultaneously edit the same code (Does it update the code live, so if I type a line of code, it will show up instantly on the others screens like Google Drive)
3. We all have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate edition because we code with XNA.. Do we need to have a certain version of Team Foundation Server to be able to use XNA/Visual Studio 2010?

Thanks alot, Matthew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I run Team Foundation Server on Linux or does it have to be
>   Windows Server?

To my knowledge you cannot, though you could always use wine.

> Can we create a project and simultaneously edit the same code (Does it
>   update the code live, so if I  type a line of code, it will show up
>   instantly on the others screens like Google Drive)

No, this is not the purpose of source control.  Code is worked on in your own "area" and then checked into a repository, at which point other people can see the code.  There are exceptions to the check in process to share code however, processes such as shelving.

Read more about the idea of source control on wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control

> We all have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate edition because we code with
>   XNA.. Do we need to have a certain version of Team Foundation Server
>   to be able to use XNA/Visual Studio 2010?

You do not need to match TFS versions to your VS version.  Are you planning on creating this server publicly exposed on the internet?  Setting up a source control server for the first time can be challenging when it's hosted internally, it will only be worse when exposed to the internet - or will you all be "together" on the same network where this is not an issue?

You could potentially look into other source controls such as Git, or Visual Studio Team Services (which can also utilize git) - this way you won't need to worry about setting it up! :O

Read more about Visual Studio Team Services: https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs

Github: https://github.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use visual studio team foundation server on the [cloud](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs) as a service, there's no installation and it's ready to go.

VS Team Services is free up to 5 users maybe that would be a good fit for your team. Follow this [instructions](https://tfs.discountasp.net/KB/a842/configure-visual-studio-2010-to-connect-to-your-team.aspx) to connect fom vs2010, it's very esasy to configure

regarding to the features you have version control among others features and so you can perform  Check-in, check-out, manage versions, or use diff/merge to collaborate and maintain control of your team’s projects.

compared to github (online version of git), you can have a private repositories online at no charge and TFS it's more easy to use, all integrated with visual studio.